# How does metropolis-hesting algorithm ensure samples obey an unknown posterior distribution

Tags: algorithm, statistics, montecarlo, markov-chains, mcmc

I'm a layman of statistics, after reading some blog and examples about Metropolis-Hastings MCMC algorithms, here i have a question:

In the M-H algorithms, a new sample(say, x')  whether be accepted depends on the "acceptance probability", alpha = min(1,A), where 
A = p(x’)q(x|x’)/[p(x)q(x’|x)].

Question comes from here,as we don't know the form of interested distribution p(x), how do we calculate the acceptance probability, which contains p(x') and p(x) ?

Or in other words: how does metropolis-hesting algorithm ensure samples obey an unknown posterior distribution.
I am a newbie, please give me some advise.

Comment: after more reading, I think P(x) is the prior distribution instead of the unknow complex posterior, so it make sence of the calculation of alpha. But if so as i sad before, how do we know the posterior(x') =  P(x')*Q(x|x') is the right posterior we looking for, is it depends on the choise of Q(x|x') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a chunk of text from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm

The lax requirement that f(x) should be merely proportional to the density, rather than exactly equal to it, makes the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm particularly useful, because calculating the necessary normalization factor is often extremely difficult in practice.
(end quote)

so your p(x) should be the probability of x under the target distribution times some unknown constant factor. One example of such a p(x) is when you impose a constraint on a known distribution. In this case you don't know p(x), but you know p(x) * K for some unknown K, so you can still calculate p(x)/p(x') = (p(x) * K) / (p(x') * K).

Suppose you want to simulate points distributed within a circle, but you didn't know the value of pi, so you couldn't work out the area of the circle. Then you could make p(x) the uniform distribution on the unit square for points <= distance 0.5 from (0.5, 0.5) and 0 elsewhere. This gives you a p(x) that integrates, not to 1, but to Pi/4, which you don't know, so it's not a proper probability distribution, but it is one times a constant factor.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it makes me understand the algorithm more clearly